# Analytical convergence of an equation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, infinity

I am reading a paper which shows the following equation:

$$
x_t = x_i + \alpha x_{t-1}
$$

Where $x_i$ is the initial value, and $\alpha$ is a simple real constant.

I am trying to ascertain if there is a way for me to (analytically) determine the convergence of $x_t$ if I am given $\alpha$ and $x_i$? I want to do this because I believe there is an error in the paper.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:   if $\,\alpha=1\,$ then $\,x_t\,$ is an arithmetic progression, otherwise $\,x_t\,$ differs by a constant from a geometric progression with common ratio $\,\alpha\,$, since:

$$
x_t = x_i + \alpha x_{t-1}
\quad\iff\quad
x_t + \dfrac{x_i}{\alpha-1} = \alpha \left(x_{t-1}+\dfrac{x_i}{\alpha-1}\right)
$$

Comment: Right - thanks. So... I am still not following how we can compute the convergence value though...

Comment: @Spacey An AP converges iff the common difference is $\,0\,$ i.e. the sequence is constant. A GP converges iff the common ratio is $\,\ldots\,$

Comment: Less than one? I've been out of school for 15 years, so I'm rusty, and this is for my job. :)

Comment: (Im also looking for how to compute the actual value this converges to). Thanks again.

Comment: @Spacey If $\,|\alpha| \lt 1\,$ then $\,x_t + \dfrac{x_i}{\alpha-1} \to 0\,$, so $\,x_t \to - \dfrac{x_i}{\alpha-1} =  \dfrac{x_i}{1-\alpha}\,$. If you somehow knew or otherwise proved that $\,x_t\,$ converges to begin with, then you could have got the limit $\,x_\infty\,$ directly by passing the recurrence relation to the limit $\,x_\infty = x_i + \alpha x_\infty$ $\iff x_\infty = \dfrac{x_i}{1-\alpha}\,$.

Comment: Beautiful thank you!